# Angular5 with HTML5 Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I try to use HTML5 Drag and Drop inside an Angular5 Component.
Where do I have to place my function in order to get it to work?

HTML example:

```
<div class="itemBox">
    <div *ngFor="let count of this.modul.getSemesterCollums(input.maxKlausur)" id="{{ count }}" class="semesterBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <a *ngFor="let item of this.modul.getArray(); let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="item.getIDSemesterInt(input.maxKlausur, this.i) == (count + 1)" id="{{ item.getName() }}" class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <p>{{item.getName()}}</p>
            <hr/>
                <ul>
                    <li>Übung: {{item.getUebungen()}}</li>
                    <li>Klausur: {{item.getKlausur()}}</li>
                    <li>Semester: {{item.getSemester()}}</li>
                    <li>Bestanden: <i class="fa fa-times"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Example:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
    else
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
}
```

it won't find it inside the component.ts and it won't find it inside "" Tags in the component.html.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: if you make a js fiddle, I might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it.

Inserted the function in the export class:

```
export class DropComponent {
    allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
            ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
        else
            ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
    }
    [.....]
}
```

And I edit the HTML as following:

```
<div class="itemBox">
<div *ngFor="let count of this.modul.getSemesterCollums(input.maxKlausur)" id="{{ count }}" class="semesterBox" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">   
    <a *ngFor="let item of this.modul.getArray(); let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="item.getIDSemesterInt(input.maxKlausur, this.i) == (count + 1)" id="{{ item.getName() }}" class="item" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
            <p>{{item.getName()}}</p>
        <hr/>
            <ul>
                <li>Übung: {{item.getUebungen()}}</li>
                <li>Klausur: {{item.getKlausur()}}</li>
                <li>Semester: {{item.getSemester()}}</li>
                <li>Bestanden: <i class="fa fa-times"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>    
</div>
</div>
```

And it works like a charm :)